# Formatting dynamically built parameter string to pass with jquery ajax in data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I would like to pass data from a dynamically built form via ajax to a php script, but have trouble finding the correct syntax for the parameter string format.
There's a couple of fixed parameters and some are added dynamically, keys and values of the latter may change.

I've tried to build the parameter list as a concatenation of strings as below:

```
...
var dataVars = '{fctSelect: 2, strat: strat, ' + gbl.dataVariables + '}';

...

$j.ajax({
    url: "ajax/script.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataVars,
...
```

gbl.dataVariables is formatted as follows : 'field1: value1, field2: value2, field3, value3'

The resulting string to go into data "looks right" in console.log, but in the post tab of the console once the field validated, it appears like this:

```
{fctSelect: 2, strat: strat, ...
```

instead of:

```
fctSelect: 2
strat: 1
...
```

meaning that the parameters are not parsed. Could someone please point me to where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darin Dimitrov's solution is probably the way to go for you, I'll just give you an alternative. If you collect your form's fields and their values through [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), you can simply append your static data like this:

```
var dataVars = $('form').serialize(),
    dataVars += dataVars.length > 0 && '&'; // in case there are no form fields
    dataVars += 'fctSelect=2&strat=somevalue';

$j.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataVars,
    success: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you an alternative approach than string concatenations:

```
var dataVars = {};

// add some static values
dataVars['fctSelect'] = 2;
dataVars['strat'] = 'some value';

// now add some dynamic values
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dataVars['field' + i] = i;
}

// send the data as a JSON encoded request
$j.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataVars),
    contentType: 'application/json',
...
```

and then inside your `script.php`:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```