# How can i set dynamic key for ajax post data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set the dynamic key in the ajax post data using jquery. My question is same as [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365846/formatting-dynamically-built-parameter-string-to-pass-with-jquery-ajax-in-data), i have followed the same way but still facing problems. Following is my ajax function

```
function DisableFunction(id,section,token){
        var dataVars = {};
        dataVars[section] = token;
        dataVars['id'] = id;
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'post.php',
        data:JSON.stringify(dataVars),
        dataType:"json",
        ...
    });
}
```

and below is my ajax call html tag attribute

```
onclick="return DisableFunction(1,'DisableNewsfeed','a6dba37437ced2c3b07469fd6c0661f3');"
```

When i click on it ajax function does not posting data properly. I attached a screenshot for ajax activity.

[image]

Can anyone kindly guide me that where is the issue that i can fix it, i would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank you.

Comment: 'not posting data properly'. Explain.

Comment: @NehalJWani I mean there is something missing, you can see in the attached screen shot

Comment: @NehalJWani Check the screenshot, i hope you will be understand that something is going wrong

Comment: I assume that you have a bunch of `if`s in your post.php file to check which key is set...  Instead of doing that and using a dynamic key in your object, consider to create another route and set the url dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot it is evident that the content type is set to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of 'application/json'

Update the ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'post.php',
        data: dataVars,
        contentType: "application/json",
        ...
    })
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't notice that. Do you think this makes sense, though: `JSON.stringify(dataVars)` ?

Comment: @AdamPatterson No, no need to stringify. Just pass the variable directly to data parameter.

Comment: You don't even need to set the contentType once you've stopped using `JSON.stringify()` @AdamPatterson

Comment: I asked so the guy that posted didn't get the wrong idea. I agree that the poster shouldn't include `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @AdamPatterson - I wrongly thought you were the OP :D

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I am not sure what id, section, and token pertain to, but in either case, the dataVars object should look something like this.

---

I'm guessing you don't want to pass JSON data to the server, but are expecting it back. So, `data: dataVars` is what you want.

I also modified your dataVars object a little bit.

```
function DisableFunction(id, section, token){
        var dataVars = {
            token: token,
            section: section,
            id: id
        };
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: dataVars,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: It set the key 'section', i want to make it dynamic. I am passing 'DisableNewsFeed' in the `section` parameter but it does not set.

Comment: It is dynamic, just make sure you name the keys properly. I had to kind of guess on the names because you only provided two out of the three necessary keys above. 

If you provide me the name of the keys I can edit it for you.